# c++11 metaprogramming: check for method existence

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

1) I have two classes `class A` and `class B` which both have a method called `foo` but with different argument lists.

```cpp
class A {
public:
  void foo(int a);
};

class B {
public:
  void foo(int a, int b);
};
```

2) Further, I have a `class C` with template argument `T` that also has a `foo` method as following

```cpp
template <typename T>
class C {
public:
  void foo();
private:
  T t_;
  int a_;
  int b_;
};
```

3) I would like use both `class A` and `class B` as template argument for `class C`.
Saying that I would like to have a method `C::foo` to be implemented like following:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void C<T>::foo()
{
  if (compile time check: T has foo(int a, int b))
   t_.foo(a_, b_);
  else
   t_.foo(a_);
}
```

How can I express the `if` statement above in `C++11`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) (with function template overloading).

```
template <typename T>
class C {
private:
    T t_;
    int a_;
    int b_;
public:
    template <typename X = T>
    auto foo() -> decltype (std::declval<X>().foo(a_)) {
        t_.foo(a_);
    }
    template <typename X = T>
    auto foo() -> decltype (std::declval<X>().foo(a_, b_)) {
        t_.foo(a_, b_);
    }
};
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/NGRBY58457)

Comment: Side note: this no longer works if `T` has both the methods (ambiguous call).

Answer (score 4):

If you know which type contains `void foo(int a, int b);` which in this case you do, you can use template specialization, something like

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
private:
  T t_;
  int a_;
  int b_;
public:
    // called for general use
    void foo()
    {
        t_.foo(a_);
    }
};

// specialized version for T = B
template<> 
void C<B>::foo()
{
    t_.foo(a_, b_);
}
```